# target img in lightgallery.js slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightgallery

Is there a way to target the `img` showed in `lightgallery.js` slider ?

This **JS** below has 3 fails to get a simple `console.log();` :

```
var $lg = $('#mosaic');
$lg.lightGallery({thumbnail: false, addClass: 'imgGallery'});

$('.imgGallery img').click(function() {
     console.log('click'); // fail
});
$('img.lg-object.lg-image').click(function() {
     console.log('click'); // fail
});
$('div.lg-img-wrap img').click(function() {
     console.log('click'); // fail
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/o5ahdnzb/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `img` elements that have the click event aren't inside the `.imgGallery` div. They're actually inside of `#mosaic`. If you change that selector to `$('#mosaic img')` you're all set for that one.

As for the other two, those elements are created dynamically, so they don't exist at the time you're trying to bind the click events. What you want is click delegation, so that you're binding the click event to an outer element, but intercepting it on a child. So create a wrapper around everything (or if not possible, bind to the body)

```
$('body').click('img.lg-object.lg-image', function(e) {
 console.log('click'); // success
 console.log(this); // body (element to which the event is bound)
 console.log(e.target); // img.lg-object.lg-image (element that received the click)
});
```

Comment: Mmmmh ok l see, thanks. How could we get the image source? 
var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src'); is undefinded

Comment: I'll update the answer to reflect this, but `function(e) { e.target.attr('src') }`

Comment: How can l save only the 'src' clicked in a variable ?

Comment: that's ok, thaks for your help!